# Vue3 Props Tree Menu Show

Tags: vue.js

this is what i want to do with vue js,
If `Menu 1` or `Menu 2` is clicked among the items with submenu, its ul will be opened, and if `Menu 1` is open, `Menu 2` is clicked. Close `Menu 1`.
I couldn't do this, I would be happy if you help me.
What I want to do is if one of the submenu is open, the 2nd submenu remains closed.

The project subject works under normal conditions, but since I made it as the component I want, it is more smooth and professional. I want it done but whichever I click on it stays open sub menu

I want to open the relevant ul when children of "li" in `MenuItems.vue` are clicked.

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71583316/vue3-tree-menu-show/)

"codesandbox" working code is ready, but it doesn't work the way I want. When I click `menu 1`, the dropdown of `menu 1` opens, and then when I click `menu 2`, `menu 1` remains open. that's not what I want.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-fixed-tree-menu-bv6wkr)
`Home`

```
<div class="container max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <Menu>
          <template v-slot:MenuItem>
            <MenuItems
              v-for="(Item, Index) in menuItem"
              :key="Index"
              :items="Item"
            />
          </template>
        </Menu>
      </div>
<script>
import Menu from "./Menu";
import MenuItems from "./MenuItems";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      menuItem: [
        {
          name: "Home",
          href: "/home",
        },
        {
          name: "About",
          href: "/about",
        },
        {
          name: "Menu 1",
          href: "#",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Menu 1.1",
              href: "/menu/1/1",
            },
            {
              name: "Menu 1.2",
              href: "/menu/1/2",
            },
            {
              name: "Menu 1.3",
              href: "/menu/1/3",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "Menu 2",
          href: "#",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Menu 2.1",
              href: "/menu/2/1",
            },
            {
              name: "Menu 2.2",
              href: "/menu/2/2",
            },
            {
              name: "Menu 2.3",
              href: "/menu/2/3",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "Gallery",
          href: "/gallery",
        },
        {
          name: "Contact",
          href: "/contact",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  components: {
    Menu,
    MenuItems,
  },
};
</script>
```

`Menu`

```
<template>
  <ul
    class="flex justify-end navbar-nav gap-3"
    itemscope
    itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
  >
    <slot name="MenuItem"></slot>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Menu",
  props: {
    menu: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`MenuItems`

```
<template>
  <li v-if="items.children" class="item dropdown">
    <MenuLink :link="items" :key="items.Index" @click="showMenu(items.Index)" />
    <ul
      class="dropdown-menu"
      :style="selected === items.Index ? 'display: block' : 'display: none'"
    >
      <MenuItems
        v-for="(child, childIndex) in items.children"
        :key="childIndex"
        :items="child"
      />
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li v-else class="item">
    <MenuLink :link="items" :key="items.Index" />
  </li>
</template>

<script>
import MenuLink from "./MenuLink";

export default {
  name: "MenuItems",
  components: {
    MenuLink,
  },
  props: {
    items: { type: Object, required: true },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    showMenu(i) {
      console.log(i);
      this.selected = i;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`MenuLink`

```
<template>
  <router-link v-if="link.children" :to="link.href">
    {{ link.name }}
  </router-link>
  <router-link v-else :to="link.href">
    {{ link.name }}
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MenuLink",
  props: {
    link: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to open the relevant ul when children of "li" in `MenuItems.vue` are clicked.

Comment: `codesandbox` working code is ready, but it doesn't work the way I want. When I click `menu 1`, the dropdown of `menu 1` opens, and then when I click `menu 2`, `menu 1` remains open. that's not what I want.